# Can we get "Enqueue" or something similar in iTunes [10.7]

Tags: macos, itunes

iTunes 10.7 is pretty awesome compared to nearly all media players/browsers I have experienced. But, just a quick question if I could have some option to get "Now Playing" list with "Enqueue" option to my audios, similar to what we have in Winamp? It would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current (and previous) version of iTunes only supports this for the iTunes DJ playlist. This playlist selects music from your library to play automatically and shows some upcoming songs. You can choose a song to be next by right-clicking (control-clicking) on it and choosing "Play Next in iTunes DJ". You can also choose "Add to iTunes DJ" to put it at the end of the list already in iTunes DJ.

The [next version](http://www.apple.com/itunes/new-itunes/) of iTunes will support this from any playlist, through the "Up Next" feature. After playing the song you choose, it will return to the playlist you were in, even if that song wasn't in the playlist.